# CloudKit private database returns first 100 CKRecords

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

i am facing this kind of problem working with CloudKit. Trying to fetch all data from "Data" record. Result is limited by 100. How to get all data? Please, thank for any advice.

```
func getAllDataFromCloudKit(){
    let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
    let container = CKContainer.defaultContainer()
    let privateDatabase = container.privateCloudDatabase
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Data", predicate: predicate)

    privateDatabase.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil) { results, error in
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
        }
        else {
            for result in results! {
                // return only 100 first 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. i found one similar question, still not clear or answer is too old and does not work with the new Swift version

**EDIT:** See my final **solution** how to get all data from private database below:

Comment: You should use `CKQueryOperation` instead of `performQuery`. You have a lot more control and you can process a lot more records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ok, i found a solution. See below:**

```
func loadDataFromCloudKit() {
    var results: [AnyObject] = []
    let cloudContainer = CKContainer.defaultContainer()
    let privateDatabase = cloudContainer.privateCloudDatabase

    let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Data", predicate: predicate)
    query.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: true)]

    let queryOperation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
    queryOperation.desiredKeys = ["id","name"]
    queryOperation.queuePriority = .VeryHigh
    // Max limit is still 100
    queryOperation.resultsLimit = 100

    queryOperation.recordFetchedBlock = { (record:CKRecord!) -> Void in
        results.append(record)
    }

    queryOperation.queryCompletionBlock = { (cursor, error) in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            if (error != nil) {
                print("Failed to get data from iCloud - \(error!.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                print("Successfully retrieve the data form iCloud")

            }
        }
        // see cursor here, if it is nil than you have no more records
        // if it has a value than you have more records to get
        if cursor != nil {
            print("there is more data to fetch")
            let newOperation = CKQueryOperation(cursor: cursor!)
            newOperation.recordFetchedBlock = { (record:CKRecord!) -> Void in
                results.append(record)
            }

            newOperation.queryCompletionBlock = queryOperation.queryCompletionBlock
            privateDatabase.addOperation(newOperation)
        } else {
            // gets more then 100
            print(results.count)
        }
    }
    privateDatabase.addOperation(queryOperation)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kevin,

You use the cursor returned by CKQueryOperation; it is very much a standard approach in the world of databases; I know some dropbox operations use the same approach for example. Here is the basic code for a CKQueryOperation.

```
func query4Cloud(theLink: String, theCount: Int) {
    var starCount:Int = 0
    let container = CKContainer(identifier: "iCloud.ch")
    let publicDB = container.publicCloudDatabase
    let singleLink2LinkthemALL = CKRecordID(recordName: theLink)
    let recordToMatch = CKReference(recordID: singleLink2LinkthemALL, action: .DeleteSelf)
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format:"theLink == %@", recordToMatch)
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Files", predicate: predicate)

    // You run the query operation replacing query with your cursor

    readerOperation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
    readerOperation.desiredKeys = ["record.recordID.recordName"];

    readerOperation.recordFetchedBlock = { (record) in
        starCount += 1
    }

   // see cursor here, if it is nil than you have no more records
   // if it has a value than you have more records to get

    readerOperation.queryCompletionBlock = {(cursor, error) in
            print("fcuk query4Cloud \(theLink) \(theCount) \(starCount)" )
            if error != nil {
                 self.showAlert(message: error!.localizedDescription)
                print("ting, busted")
            } else {
                // it's done
            }

    }
    print("publicDB.addOperation(operation)")
    readerOperation.qualityOfService = .Background
    publicDB.addOperation(readerOperation)
}
```

Comment: It does not look really basic to me. I just simply need to read all privateDatabase record. Anyways, thank you. Will try to implement.